# Github action input without parameters

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, workflow, building-github-actions

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have the following github code, it doesn't take input parameters, I just need it to be able to execute the action on github when I want.

But github marks me as a warning, how can I do?

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:

name: Build
jobs:
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need it to be able to execute the action on github when I want.

That sounds like a manual trigger: [**Manually running a workflow**](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow).

```
on: workflow_dispatch
```

(ref: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch)

It shows its default form with no further elements like the `inputs` you have. Just remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `inputs` line altogether:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

name: Build
...
```

Mind that the name of the branch will still be an input parameter, selectable in the GitHub UI.